# Done button in NumberKeyPad Causing Issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uikeyboard

Code Used to add done button in Numberkeypad

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // create custom button
    doneButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (IS_iOS_7_OR_LATER) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIView *keyboardView = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] subviews] firstObject];
            [doneButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardView.frame.size.height - 53, 106, 53)];
            [keyboardView addSubview:doneButton];
            [keyboardView bringSubviewToFront:doneButton];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]-.02
                                  delay:.0
                                options:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]
                             animations:^{
                                 self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 0);
                             } completion:nil];
        });
    }else {
        // locate keyboard view
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
            UIView* keyboard;
            for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
                keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
                if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                    [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have written code to add done button in number keypad its working perfectly with device's default keyboard the problem arises if the device is installed with third party keyboard [swift keys App] is there a way to identify the third party Keyboard to solve this issue

Thanks in Advance!

[image: Device Default Keyboard]
[image: Device Installed With Custom Keyboard]

Comment: It seems you want a custom keyboard, so why not make one?

Comment: @Mats I just need a normal numberkeypad with done button No need of custom keyboard I will take your suggestion, if there is no solution for this probably I should got with your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want, I know one way but exactly not you said;
You don't need any third party library for this method
you just create UIBarButton and add button to UIToolbar and finally just add you created toolbar after you implement it

```
YourNumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = textFieldToolBar;
```

here is a code

```
UIToolbar* textFieldToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
textFieldToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
textFieldToolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear All" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector("YourClearButtonFunctionName")],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Ok!" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector("YourOkButtonFunctionName")],
                       nil];
[textFieldToolBar sizeToFit];
YourNumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = textFieldToolBar;
```

Comment: I tried this but it looks odd in numberkeypad. already there is a empty space in bottom left of numberkeypad and we  are adding tool bar to it

Comment: there is no way to add button on UIKeyboard, because its looks the same  iOS developer library sample code here is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009462-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

but if you try another way like create a new view and add right frame on keyboard here is code I'm talking about maybe its help you 
https://github.com/dazuiba/dz-numberpad-done-helper